# Website is loaded diffrent when loaded in https and http?

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

I Am New To Stackoverflow So Sorry If I Didn't Write Enough Information...
I Am New To Networking And Made Me A Site(I Didn't Programm It Used A Software To Make It) And Now Recently I Have Put On A SSL Certificate From Let's Encrypt But Now Whenever I Load My Site In HTTPS It Loads With This Weired Font Which Isn't There When I Load It In HTTP. Could It Be Because Of The Hosting Provider(GoDaddy) Or On The Website Itself? And Also Whenever Loaded In HTTPS Chrome Says There Are Scripts From Unathentified Sources Whys That?
Here Is The Link To My Website:
https://www.bharathsweb.com/
http://www.bharathsweb.com/
Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 1):

Because your font are not getting loaded since your CSS file is not on HTTPS. Take a look at the https screenshot of your website.

[image: https page of your website]